# Looking for ticket creation/logging software

Tags: database, logs, booking

I am looking for a free software to print tickets and log entries into a text/Excel file. It needs to do these few things:

1. Have an area where user can input name, and have a local account of sorts.
2. Have an area where user can input dimension, (LxWxH), which will then be calculated into volume
3. Have an area where user can select item from drop down menu, which would be from admin-database
4. Have an area where user can put where item was from
5. Log the data into separate Excel or Text files for every user. It should be formatted something like this:

Name Date Origin Volume Item from drop down

It should also be able to print that information to a ticket. Summarizing, I need a software that will allow people to input the dimensions of an object, and an item from the drop down menu, origin, and their name and get a document with the volume, drop down item, and name. Every time the user enters a new object, it should simply add the volume and have a total at the bottom of the page. Printed tickets should look like this:

Name: John Doe
Date: 11/8/2022 15:05
Origin: Car
Volume: 64in3
Drop Down Item:

I don't even know what to search for, and I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. Any help would be  greatly appreciated!

I have no idea where to even start, I tried searching for POS software, then a GUI designer, but I have had no luck.